# Bellman - Ford algorithm in "Introduction to Algorithms 3rd Edition" by CLRS(Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein)

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

[image]

I am reading "Introduction to Algorithms 3rd Edition" by CLRS.

There are the following sentences in this book:

> The Bellman-Ford algorithm solves the single-source shortest-paths problem in
>   the general case in which edge weights may be negative. Given a weighted, directed graph $G = (V, E)$ with source $s$ and weight function $w : E \to \mathbb{R}$, the
>   Bellman-Ford algorithm returns a boolean value indicating whether or not there is
>   a negative-weight cycle that is reachable from the source. If there is such a cycle, the algorithm indicates that ***no solution exists***.

I think maybe there is a solution for some vertex $v$ even if there is a negative-weight cycle that is reachable from the source.

Please see the above picture.
There is a solution for $v$ and $\delta(s, v) = 5$.

Why does this algorithm give up finding the distance from $s$ to $v$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bellman-Ford computes the shortest path from the "source" $s$ to *all* other vertices. If there's *some* vertex $k$ for which $d(s, v)$ is undefined (because of a negative-weight cycle, for instance), then the problem is unsolvable, because a solution consists of shortest paths to **all** vertices. In your example, there's no shortest path from $s$ to the topmost vertex, as running around the triangle multiple times can always "shorten" the path.

Comment: Thank you John Hughes for your answer. $\delta(s, s) = 0$, $\delta(s, v) = 5$ and $\delta(s, u) = -\infty$ for any vertex $u \in V - \{s, v\}$. But there is no solution?

Comment: Right: the problem isn't to compute the *length* of the shortest path (or the min of the lengths of all possible paths, which is what $\delta$ gives you): it's to find the (or a) shortest path, and for $s$ and the top vertex, there is no shortest path.

Comment: Oh sorry. There is no shortest path to $u$.

Comment: Thank you very much.